# Array to string conversion error in laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

i am trying to do this sql query in eloquent:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(capacitaciones.fv, '$date') AS diff FROM capacitaciones INNER JOIN users ON capacitaciones.id_usuario = users.documento WHERE DATEDIFF(capacitaciones.fv, '$date') < 30 AND DATEDIFF(capacitaciones.fv, '$date') > 0"
```

i did it this way:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
    $reporte2 = Reporte::selectRaw('*, datediff( ? ,capacitaciones.fi)',[$date])
    ->join('users','capacitaciones.id_usuario','=','users.documento')
    ->whereRaw(' datediff(? , capacitaciones.fi < ?)',[$date],[30])
    ->get();
```

and tried to pass it to a view like this

```
return view('livewire.pages.reportes',compact('reporte2'));
```

but I get the error Array to string conversion, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I don't know the syntax very well, What did I do wrong?

Comment: I believe at the `whereRaw` should possibly be: `whereRaw(' datediff(? , capacitaciones.fi < ?)', [$date, 30])`?

Comment: thanks for the comment you gave me the idea and I solved it : ->whereRaw(' datediff(capacitaciones.fi, ? ) < ?', [$date, 30])